# Music Loop in Java

Tags: java, audio, background-music

Good day!

I am doing a game and I want it to have a background sound. I created a class for it and I call it on my main. My code is as follows:

```
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class Sound {

        public void music() {

            AudioStream backgroundMusic;
            AudioData musicData;
            AudioPlayer musicPlayer = AudioPlayer.player;
            ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
            try {
                backgroundMusic = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("chickendance.wav"));
                musicData = backgroundMusic.getData();
                loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(musicData);
                musicPlayer.start(loop);
            } catch (IOException error) { System.out.println(error);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my main class where i call it.

```
public class HangmanLauncher extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public HangmanLauncher() {
            initComponents();
            Sound sound = new Sound();
            sound.music();
        }
```

My problem is that the music doesn't play. `Error: java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream.` What does it mean? The type of my file is Microsoft Wave Sound Format and its size is 796kb.  May I know what I am doing wrong? Your suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you know there is no error when you are catching the `IOException` but not doing anything with it? Your `Sound` can just fail silently, for instance if the file isn't found.

Comment: ah okay. thank you for pointing that out. forgot to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the `wav` file has been encoded in a format the `AudioStream` class doesn't understand. I couldn't find the docs for the class (??) but I would try another file that isn't `Microsoft Wave Sound`. Again, don't know the specifics of that encoding but it being Microsoft it's probably proprietary and therefore not in the Sun implementation of the `AudioStream`.

Answer (score 3):

I can play .wav files using the following code.

Mind you if you are using a JFrame you will likely want to play your sound file in a Thread so you can continue other operations.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

AudioInputStream as1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new java.io.FileInputStream("chickenDance.wav"));
               AudioFormat af = as1.getFormat();
               Clip clip1 = AudioSystem.getClip();
               DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af);

               Line line1 = AudioSystem.getLine(info);

               if ( ! line1.isOpen() )
               {
                clip1.open(as1);
                clip1.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                clip1.start();
               }
```

Answer (score 3):

so i've been trying to do this myself and i found how to implement it finally
This particular code chooses a track at random from the directory given and then loop choosing another random file
The loop is in the startPlayback() which is called from the run() method, as this is a seperate thread this will not stop program execution

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
/**
 *
 * @author Mangusbrother
 */

public class MusicPlayer extends Thread {private AudioStream as;
private AudioPlayer p;
private boolean playback;

public void run() {
    startPlayback();
}

private void setRandom() {
    File[] files = getTracks();
    try {
        String f = files[(int) (Math.random() * (files.length - 1))].getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Now Playing: " + f);
        as = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MusicPlayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void startPlayback() {
    playback = true;
    setRandom();
    p.player.start(as);
    try {
        do {
        } while (as.available() > 0 && playback);
        if (playback) {
            startPlayback();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MusicPlayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

public void stopPlayback() {
    playback = false;
    p.player.stop(as);
}

private File[] getTracks() {
    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\music");
    File[] a = dir.listFiles();
    ArrayList<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (File f : a) {
        if (f.getName().substring(f.getName().length() - 3, f.getName().length()).equals("wav")) {
            list.add(f);
        }
    }
    File[] ret = new File[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        ret[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is mp3-only, but if that's an option, check out JLayer and friends: http://www.javazoom.net/projects.html

Answer (score 2):

I produce an AudioInputStream from a Wave like this:

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new FileInputStream("chickendance.wav"));
```

I don't play it though.

Answer (score 0):

I Used .au file format and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many different ways of playing audio, and I have found this to be my most successful class file that does so.

```
package Classes;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import sun.audio.AudioData;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;
public class SoundLoader2 implements Runnable{
    public AudioPlayer Player = AudioPlayer.player;
    public AudioStream Stream = null;
    public AudioData data=null;
    InputStream inputStream=null;
    InputStream inputStream2=null;
    InputStream Stream2=null;
    public ContinuousAudioDataStream loop;
    public String url;
    public URL Url;
    public boolean repeat;
    public SoundLoader2(String url,boolean repeat)throws IOException{
    this.repeat=repeat;
    Url=getClass().getResource(url);
     inputStream = Url.openStream();
     inputStream2 = Url.openStream();
        Stream=new AudioStream(inputStream);
        data=Stream.getData();
        loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(data);
        Stream2=new AudioStream(inputStream2);
    }
    public void play(){
    if(this.repeat==true){
        Player.start(loop);
        }
        else if(this.repeat==false);
        Player.start(Stream2);
        }
    @Override
    public void run() {
      play();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the info, with above help and some others i have this code which works:

```
public void play(InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream soundIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream) );
        AudioFormat format = soundIn.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(soundIn);
        clip.start();
        sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);// Thread.yield();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("could not play");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sleep(long sleep) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleep);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```