# How to play mp3 file in a loop, with pause and restart option in java?

Tags: java, javasound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Music Loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875080/music-loop-in-java)

Currently I am using this code to play a mp3 file

```
public void run(String url) {
    try {
            ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
            InputStream in;
            in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(url);

            Player p = new Player(in);
            p.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print(url + e);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I want to make it loop forever. I have also created a button named New. When I click the new button, I want it to play from start, and also how can I pause it? I have googled it, but I couldnot understand anything. Previously I was able to make loop a .wav file. But I got stuck for the .mp3 file. I am using jlayer 1.0.1

Can any one please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound, which has a really easy-to-use API for this sort of thing.