# Playing music continuously in the loop in java

Tags: java

I have written this code for playing music in my java program, but I want to play the music continuously in the loop, for that I have tried an infinite loop as well but it is not working. Please tell how it possible to play the music continuously?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import sun.audio.*;

public class A {


    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {       

        AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
        AudioStream BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("sounds.wav"));
        AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM);
    }
}
```

Comment: Give a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875080/music-loop-in-java?answertab=votes#tab-top

Read mangusbrother's answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDoc:

To play a continuous sound you first have to create an AudioData instance and use it to construct a ContinuousAudioDataStream. For example:

```
 AudioData data = new AudioStream(url.openStream()).getData();
 ContinuousAudioDataStream audiostream = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(data);
 AudioPlayer.player.start(audiostream);
```

I really didn't think it would be that difficult to adapt the docs.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import sun.audio.*;

public class A {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {    

        AudioData data = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("yourfile.wav")).getData();
        ContinuousAudioDataStream BGM = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(data);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3779397 That's *your* job. It's not Erik's responsibility to write code for you. Be adaptable.

Comment: @user3779397, thanks. I went ahead and just tested the changes myself since I needed a break from what I'm working on. They work fine and I've updated the answer.

Comment: @user3779397, please read the docs for StackOverflow. We're here to help (which is something I enjoy doing). We are not here to do all of your work for you.

Comment: @user3580294, doh! Sorry. Had just jumped back into doing 5 different things at once. Yes, those comments are reversed. Thank you for pointing out what StackOverflow is about to the questioner! I fixed the second comment, but the first is locked.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek Been there, done that. It's certainly easy to accidentally lose track of things when multitasking. Glad I could help, although it turned out that you came back at the same time I posted...

Comment: Please help! This code is throwing (java.io.IOException) at (A.java:8)